# How can i make it so "The " is skipped while listing by first letter in Sphinx query

Tags: mysql, sphinx

I need to replicate results with Sphinx previously done with mysql.

I have single index built that holds 3 example fields:

artistname | songname | lyricstext

NOTE * need to clarify, the original multimillion tables come as mysql tables (fully emptied and imported anew), where they are imported into mysql first. Index source is single query linking these tables together.

by using sphinxql commands I need to achieve the next:

match and list by first letter from fields "artistname" and "songname" while ignoring "the " if found.

following these rules, listing by first letter "w" would include (examples):

1. Whitney Houston
2. The Who

The results need to be sorted by weight.

List by first letter "B" would yield result by weight:

1. B  / Single letter /  100
2. B-T / Single letter + non-alphabet sign after /  90
3. B as Blue / Single letter + space after / 80
4. Baccara / First letter of single word / 70
5. Bad Religion / First letter of several words / 60
6. The B  / not counting "The " / 50
7. The B.Y.Z  / Single letter + non-alphabet sign after not counting "The " / 40
8. The B 2 B  / Single letter + space after  not counting "The " / 30
9. The Boyzz / First letter of single word not counting "The " / 20
   10.The Blue Boy / First letter of several words not counting "The " / 10

===================================================

Full-Text Search can be done on any of the fields

What is our option to control the tolerance (the number of the possible misplaced/missing letters in a string) in the search?

example search for "beatle" would:

match "The Beatles"
would match "beatles"

===================================================
example search string "don"

Results by weight:

1. Don / weight 100 - first position single word - perfect match/
2. Don a tello / weight 90 -first position several words /
3. Mon Don Atel O / weight 80 - non-first position several words /
4. Monade Don / weight 70 - last position several words /

I know it looks much, but all this translates into several queries. I just don't have the needed level of expertise to produce it.

Last but not least, how should I build up the index with what options so I can use the full power of sphinx while working with these queries?

Comment: You need to transform the text before submitting to full-text matching. Remove the pattern "^The/s" from haystack, let the engine calculate the relevance scores, then print the unmodified column values.

Comment: This needs to be done without altering the original values. Weekly multimillion row update makes it impossible for this to be done before-hand. I was hopping that there is an option for this to be done on indexing or pre-querying

Comment: Sphinx has a dedicated stopword feature

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-stopwords

that might help. Mysql has a stopword list too, but its hardcoded, search the web to find the list of words used. Not sure about the rest of the questions, your post is rather tl;dr

Comment: I appreciate all comments made on assumption rather on facts. Thanks.